# How do I do conditional logic within an ASP.NET DataRepeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, asp.net-2.0, datarepeater

I'm binding my DataRepeater control to a table that has many columns.   I'd like to only display a subset of those, depending on what is populated.

How/where should I do my contitional tests within a dataRepeater?  This is the code within my itemtemplate:

```
<% if (0= (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "first").ToString().Length))
{
   i++;
}
    %>
```

The error I get is: CS0103: The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be fine with this:

```
<% if (0 == (Eval("first").ToString().Length))
{
   i++;
}
%>
```

But depending on what you want to do, I would probably write a function to handle the binding of the data in order to retain separation between display and business logic.

e.g.

in your aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" runat="server" onDataItemBound="FillInRepeater">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="contactLarge">
    <div style="background-color:#C5CED8;clear:both"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="title"></asp:Label>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
</AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

in your code-behind:

```
protected void FillInRepeater(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
  {
    //in here you bind to your repeater labels and stuff then do all that sorta logic.
    //Grab Primary Data
    string titleText = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "title").ToString();
    string somethingElseText = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "somethingElse").ToString();
    string maybeSeeMaybeDontText = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "maybeSeeMaybeDont").ToString();

    //Find the controls and populate them according the to row
    Label titleLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("title");
    Label somethingElseLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("somethingElse");
    Label maybeSeeMaybeDontLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("maybeSeeMaybeDont");

    // display the fields you want to
    titleLabel.Text = titleText;
    somethingElseLabel.Text = somethingElseText;

    // here is where you could do some of your conditional logic
    if (titleText.Length != 0 && somethingElseText.Length != 0)
    {
        maybeSeeMaybeDontLabel.Text = maybeSeeMaybeDontText;
    }
  }
}
```

personally, I prefer to do things this way rather than doing any logic inside the ASP. I know that it might seem a bit silly to some people, but I like to keep my business logic separate from my display logic whereever possible.

Comment: @samandmoore No luck getting DatBinder.Eval to work as you describe.  It requires two objects in the method call.

Comment: fyi My repeater has some HTML that I'd like to conditionally display.  "i" tracks the number of items that are displayed per item.  So, for example if lines 3 through 5 are null, then I have room to display lines 6 though 9.

Comment: @MakerOfThings7 I fixed up the first part. it works fine with just `Eval("first")` for me. try that.

Comment: @samandmoore  I now get the exception: Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Comment: I have a sample here: http://www.perfmon.com/download/ContactsGrid_Null_DataRepeater.zip  
... just be sure remove the "callback" control within the usercontrol; you probably don't have that object installed

Comment: The only problem I have with that solution is that I can't control the rendering of "<div style="background-color:#C5CED8;clear:both">" if the label is blank.  All the extra DIV's with null data will render and mess up my format.  I'm shooting for a dynamic format.  I *DO* like the separation of data you're doing :)

Comment: Due to the simplicity of my need, i went with a lit control, strinbuilder and string formatting. Going back to asp.net from MVC is tough :P Everything is so difficult, even simple things. The new databinding in asp.net 4.5 will solve a lot of that though.