# IF Else in repeater

Tags: asp.net

Please help I am trying to add a condition in repeater, the code I am using is not working. Please have a look and provide me solution, here is my code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myID" runat="server" onitemcommand="rptjobs_ItemCommand1">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="row custom_bdrbtm">
        <div class="col-md-9 custom_bdrrgt"><asp:Label ID="lbljobTitle1"    runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobTitle")%>'></asp:Label>
            <%# Eval("Description").ToString().Length >150%> ? <p> <%# Eval("Description").ToString().Substring(0,150)%> .....</p> : <%# Eval("Description").ToString()%></div>

              </div>

      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

I hope I have explained my problem
Thanks!

Comment: Not working how?  Simply saying not working is like going to the doctor and saying you don't feel well and expecting a diagnosis....

Comment: Your conditional check is outside of the server side code, The Question Mark/Colon notation needs to be within the <%# %> tags.  It's possible to do conditionally formatting this way, but after a while it's gets messy :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do an if else based on the data, if I understood this correctly. In which case I think you should be doing this while the data is being bound to the control.

[This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464470/how-do-i-do-conditional-logic-within-an-asp-net-datarepeater-control) discusses handling the onDataItemBound of the repeater.

> I tried posting this as a comment, but I dont have enough reputation to post a comment and hence I have posted this as an answer